# Maximizing function in 2 variables with constraint in 3

Tags: optimization

\begin{gather*} 
  \max &{3x_1-x_2+x_2^3} \\
  s.t. &x_1+x_2+x_3 \leq 0 \\
  &-x_1+2x_2+x_3^2=0  
 \end{gather*}
    I calculated the partial derivatives:
    $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}= 3$$
    $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}= -1+3x_2^2$$
    $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3}= 0$$
In order to use the KKT condition, but how should I proceed with the 3rd derivative equal null? And should I convert it in minimization problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the last equation for $x_3$ and plug it into the inequality constraint.  You want the negative square root to make the inequality easy to satisfy.